# Java Multithreading ExecutorService Implementation for loops

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have the code below:-

```
for (final String str : ListA) {
            for (final String str1 : ListB) {
                for (final String str2 : listC) {

                    executor.execute(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //make an API call here
                        }
                    });

                }

            }

        }
```

Basically i want to make API calls based on three strings `(str, str1, str2)`. So instead of looping it i want to make the loop execute paralelly in java 7. Lets say `str2` has 3 values `{a,b,c}` and `str2` has 4 values`{1,2,3,4}` and str has two values:`{x,y}` then i want to make all combinations here. lets say if str has x, and str2 has 1 for the intial looping now i want to make these calls parallel like:-

```
http:apicall/x/1/a,http:apicall/x/1/b,http:apicall/x/1/c.
```

So basically here i would like to start three threads and complete the inner most loop in one go parallely to complete it.

I am making use of executor service here. But i think my above approach is incorrect as i think its running the loops more than what i expect there. Can any one please suggest or correct me here please.

Comment: Please don't repeat questions as this is not allowed.

Comment: Hi @HovercraftFullOfEels. Actually its quite different. that question over there is about how can i implement executor service with in loops and i have completed that by karthikdivi suggestion and now i have a different question here. I have posted what i have tried here and asking for suggestions where i was wrong and i was more interested for new answers which might be a better solution for this. So after this explanation, if you feel the same can you please remove the duplicate tag for this please?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels basically what i am trying to say is the answer over there didnt worked and hence i want to make a new post with what i have tried based on previous suggestions. So i believe there is a neccessity of a new question here. So please i request you to correct me if im in a worng perspective as i am new to stackoverflow as well.